# Error message when calling Unity Animator.Play() : Invalid Layer -1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I am trying to do a simple animation with a simple state machine, but Unity prints out an error message:

***Invalid Layer Index '-1' 
UnityEngine.Animator:Play(String, Int32, Single)***

I have verified that my animator state machine is located in the "Base Layer", which should have the ID = -1 by default.

In addition, I have printed out all the layer IDs in my games, and they are all "-1", and I am not sure if that is the correct answer because I thought that each layer should have a unique (or different) ID ?

However, regardless, Unity still prints out the same error above unfortunately.

I am using the latest version of Unity 5.5.2

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Thanh_Space_Man : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {   

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
        {           
            anim.Play ("Run_Rifle_Foreward", -1, 0f);           
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
        {
            anim.Play ("Idle_Rifle_01", -1, 0f);
        }


    }
}
```

FYI: I am a beginner in Unity. :-)

Comment: Is the animation state definitely spelled correctly? i.e. "Run_Rifle_Forward". This has to be exactly the same as one of the animation states.

Comment: Yes, it is spelled correctly. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: -1 means it isn't found, I think. Meaning when you printed it you did something wrong. I've done the same mistake! I think the first layer starts at 1.

Comment: Here's how you'd check: `LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI")` --> 5

Comment: @Fredrik:  from this Unity document https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html , it shows that method Play() takes in -1 as the default argument for the layer.

Comment: Oh, indeed! My bad

Comment: @Fredrik: I just used your code "LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI") to get the IDs of the layers, and it says that all my layers have the same ID of -1. Does it sound correct ? I thought that each layer should have a unique (different) ID from the others ?

Comment: Indeed, -1 is the default which is "No Layer" I think. There are 2 different layers, `Layer`s and `SortingLayer`s. I remember having the same issue but when I checked the code I found myself using the NameToLayer("UI")... Does the specified Layer you're trying to get exist? Is it a Layer and not a SortingLayer?

Comment: I just tried myself; it seems to work here. I'll show you the results I get in an answer

Comment: As you can see, the layers are case sensitive, -1 means the layer doesn't exist and Default is 0.

Answer (score 1):

These are the values I get when using LayerMask.NameToLayer where "CustomLayer" is a layer I created manually in the [Tags & Layer manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html).

```
Debug.Log(LayerMask.NameToLayer("asd")); // => -1
Debug.Log(LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI")); // => 5
Debug.Log(LayerMask.NameToLayer("CustomLayer")); // => 8
Debug.Log(LayerMask.NameToLayer("customlayer")); // => -1
Debug.Log(LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default")); // => 0
```

---

Update:

OP found the issue:

> I've just figured out that the error is that I was incorrectly spelled the name of the animation state when I called Animator.Play(). After I use the correct name of the state, then it works fine. It is even more interesting that regardless of whether I pass in the Layer ID as 0 or -1, when I call Animator.Play(), it works in both cases.

Comment: My layers are listed as: Everything, Nothing, Default, UI, Water,... Each of these layers have a unique (different) IDs as yours.  However, when I call anim.Play ("Run_Rifle_Forward",   ID, 0f); and pass in the integer ID such as 1, 2, 4, or 5, Unity always says "Invalid Layer index 1" or 2 or 4 or 5... That is strange. I am thinking there is something else that is wrong here in my code or my scene is not set up correctly...

Comment: Oh ok, sorry - I thought you were having issues with the NameToLayer. I will try to reproduce your issue

Comment: Thanks, Fredrik.  I learned some debug technique from you. :-)

Comment: I've just figured out that the error is that I was incorrectly spelled the name of the animation state when I called Animator.Play().  After I use the correct name of the state, then it works fine. It is even more interesting that regardless of whether I pass in the Layer ID as 0 or -1, when I call Animator.Play(), it works in both cases. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. The reason was that I added a new object with a new animator but forgot to change in the Awake:

```
_myAnimator = FindObjectOfType<Animator>(); // just one animator in scene
```

to

```
_myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>(); // own animator of that object
```

After changing those lines for both objects everything worked fine.